# Find the constants b and c such that the limit is 1

Tags: probability, analysis

Let $p_n$ be the probability that $2n$ independent fair coin flips result in precisely $n$ HEADS. Find the constants $b$ and $c$ such that
$$
\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}{\frac{p_n}{bn^c}}=1
$$

I can get $p_n=C_{2n}^{n}(\frac{1}{2})^n (\frac{1}{2})^n$, so wo need to compute b and c that satisfy
$$
\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n}n!n!n^c}=b
$$

Can you tell me how to compute it?

Comment: You can try to use Stirling's approximation for factorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you know [Stirling's approximaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation), that $n! \approx \frac {n^n}{e^n}\sqrt{2 \pi n}$?  It is quite accurate